Delays in Playing Sound in Javascript, with jspsyche Plugin (jspsych-libet)
I am experiencing delays in playing a beep tone using the jspsyche plugin called jspsych-libet for my experiment. The timing of the sound is crucial, but I have observed delays of up to 400ms.  These delays occur randomly and are relatively rare.
Upon examining the code, it appears to be straightforward. After a button click, there is a fixed 250ms timer set for playing the sound. However, the delay seems to exceed this value. Here is the code snippet where the beep is played:
setTimeout(function() {
    // play the tone
    if (context !== null) {
        startTime = context.currentTime;
        source.start(startTime);
    } else {
        audio.play();
    }
    // record cock hand angle of audio
    trial_data.theta_tone = clock.theta;
    trial_data.tone_ms = performance.now();
    // trigger estimation?
    ctrl_fcn('estimate');
}, trial.tone_delay_ms);

This code utilizes both the Web Audio API and HTML5 audio. I have attempted to use both methods, but the issue persists.
Here is the section where the audio is loaded:
// load audio
var context = jsPsych.pluginAPI.audioContext();
var audio;
// load audio file
jsPsych.pluginAPI.getAudioBuffer(trial.tone_file)
  .then(function (buffer) {
    if (context !== null) {
      audio = context.createBufferSource();
      audio.buffer = buffer;
      audio.connect(context.destination);
    } else {
      audio = buffer;
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
    // start the trial
    ctrl_fcn('start');
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(`Failed to load audio file "${trial.tone_file}". Please check the file path. We recommend using the preload plugin to load audio files.`);
    console.error(err);
  });

I have researched and came across suggestions regarding preloading, but preloading (either with web audio api or the jspsyche) doesn't seem to resolve the problem. I have also attempted alternative audio libraries like Howler.js, but the issue persists.
Also I've noticed that the occurrence rate can noticeably go higher when the RAM usage is high.
I'd appreciate it if you have any ideas that might help.

Using setTimeout() is not very accurate. It only guarantees that the callback will be called after the time has elapsed but not that it will be called exactly at that time.
But you could use the Web Audio API directly to schedule something very precisely.
Something like the following should do it.
source.start(context.currentTime + trial.tone_delay_ms / 1000);


Thank you for your response. I tried it and it didn't solve the problem and it still happens sometimes. I understand that using setTimeout is not ideal for precise timing, but I think something like 200ms error is still huge, even for setTimeout.

I'm happy to help you debugging it further if you could provide a little isolated demo on StackBlitz, CodeSandbox, Glitch, ... or any of the other services.
